# Cómo ocultar del codigo fuente los divs desactivados

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber si es posible ocultar divs que se encuentran con **display none** para que así al momento de darle click en **inspeccionar elemento** y también al dar click en **ver codigo fuente** no aparezcan estos div, si no que aparezcan cuando se encuentren activos, como si fuera un metodo de ofuscación, en el lenguaje de blogger se puede hacer pero quiero hacerlo esta vez con javascript ¿existe manera de hacerlo?

```css
.box{
background-color: #ddd;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
.oculto{
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="oculto" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="oculto" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="oculto" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="oculto" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="oculto" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Utilizas jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que los elementos dejen de ser visibles y ademas no pueda verse el código fuente al inspeccionar la pagina puedes remover dichos elementos del DOM y guardar su contenido en una variable js:

```js
var caja = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
var divs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('oculto')];

function ocultar(){
  divs.map(e => caja.removeChild(e));
}

function mostrar(){
  divs.map(e => caja.appendChild(e));
}
```

```css
.box{
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.oculto{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="ocultar()">Ocultar</button>
<button onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar</button>


<div class="box">
  <div class="oculto" >
    Contenido 1
  </div>
  <div class="oculto" >
    Contenido 2
  </div>
  <div class="oculto" >
    Contenido 3
  </div>
  <div class="oculto" >
    Contenido 4
  </div>
  <div class="oculto" >
    Contenido 5
  </div>
</div>
```

Puedes probar este ejemplo y ver que luego de ocultar los elementos tampoco puede verse su contenido con el inspector.

Así es como se en el inspector cuando se muestran los elementos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así se ve el inspector cuando se ocultan:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener los elementos por clase se puede usar `document.getElementsByClassName()`.
para removerlos `removeChild()` y para volverlos a agregar `appendChild()`,

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: El problema con esta solución es que si se van a ver **en el código fuente**.

Comment: @Marcos para evitar eso tendría que obtener los divs con ajax.

Comment: Si, esa seria una solucion

Answer (score -1):

Necesitarías un contenedor vacío y llenarlo por JS

HTML

```
<section id="container"></section>
```

JS

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'div';
div.onclick = function() {
  del this;
}
var divs = [div, div, div];

function addDivs() {
  divs.foreach( element => {
    container.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Hola Mike, creo que no entendiste muy bien la pregunta del OP.